# Ant scp task failure

Tags: ant, scp

I have one requirement: copy local files to remote system.
I have done the following:

1. downloaded jsch-0.1.44.jar and copied to lib folder of Ant
2. set the path and every thing

My buildfile is:

```
<project name="ImportedBuild" default="all">
  <target name="copyFileToRemote">
    <echo>2222222222 copyFileToRemote Examples:::::::::::::</echo>
    <scp file="sample.txt" todir="${username}:${password}@${hostname}:/shared"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

When I run Ant, I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 10.184.74.168
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:712)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:313)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:212)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.upload(Scp.java:291)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp.execute(Scp.java:203)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    ... etc ...
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: It'd be worth editing your question body to include the buildfile.  You can also format code, logs, etc., to make them a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the [Ant `scp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) docs, `trust` attribute:

> This trusts all unknown hosts if set
>   to yes/true. Note If you set this to
>   false (the default), the host you
>   connect to must be listed in your
>   knownhosts file, this also implies
>   that the file exists.

The `trust` attribute is not used in your task call, so it appears that the host (10.184.74.168) is not in your knownhosts file.  Suggest you add `trust="true"`, or add the host to the knownhosts file.

Comment: @user617228 is the host already in your known_hosts but with a different hostkey? try deleting all entries for this host in the known_hosts and test with trust="true"

Answer (score 3):

Be sure your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file is using un-hashed hostnames; if the lines start `|1|base64data...`, JSch appears unable to parse them. Create lines of the format `hostname[,hostname|ip]* ssh-keytype base64data...`.

See `man 8 sshd` on the precise format of known_hosts, and tips on where to find the host's public key.

Comment: Your hint helped me to solve my issue. However I had to generate the known_hosts file manually via the JSch interface. It seems as JSch is quite selective on the supported formats.