# Ant scp throwing java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, ant

I'm trying to copy files to a remote server via ssh using Ant in Eclipse (ubuntu), using the task below:

```
<scp todir="root@[x.x.x.x]:/var/www/client"
        keyfile="redacted"
        passphrase="redacted"
        >
        <fileset dir="./WebContent">
            <include name="**/*.html"/>
        </fileset>
    </scp>
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: [x.x.x.x]
```

Both jsch-0.1.54.jar and ant-jsch.jar are locate within $ANT_HOME/lib.

I can ping x.x.x.x and use the same keyfile and passphrase to login via ssh from the shell, no issues.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have square brackets around the ip?

Comment: I added the brackets because I was getting a "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey" exception, following a suggestion on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031381/1496890 . However, it appears that the brackets are not needed and adding "trust = yes" solves the "reject HostKey" exception, although I'm not sure why it happens as the host key was added to known_hosts upon opening an ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the square brackets from the IP address (solves the "UnknownHostException") and adding "trust = yes" to the ant script (solves the previous "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey" problem):

```
<scp todir="root@x.x.x.x:/var/www/client"
        keyfile="redacted"
        passphrase="redacted"
        trust = "yes"
        >
        <fileset dir="./WebContent">
            <include name="**/*.html"/>
        </fileset>
</scp>
```